# OSX Yosemite Apache Segmentation fault(11)

Tags: php, macos, apache, symfony, osx-yosemite-beta

Hello I installed Yosemite public Beta configured the Apache and installed the Liip php-osx for Symfony2 Development.

If i try to access the app_dev.php i get this errors.

[Fri Aug 29 22:20:43.197239 2014] [core:notice] [pid 5582] AH00052: child pid 5594 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

i tried to switch off some modules and added them again. 
After loading module mod_dir.so apache fails again.

Anyone has the same Problem?

Comment: What code/call in `app_dev.php` triggers the fault?

Comment: $response = $kernel->handle($request);